# Why pthread_exit acts like pthread_join?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, pthread-join, pthread-exit

Code:

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
   sleep(3);
   cout<<"Still PrintHello is alive"<<endl;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   cout<<"Calling thread:"<<t<<endl;
   pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, PrintHello, NULL);
   //pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
   cout<<"Main exits"<<endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Why `pthread_exit(NULL)` here acts like `pthread_join()`? i.e Why exiting `main` not destroying the `printHello` thread and allowing it to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_exit()` terminates only the calling thread. So when you call it from `main()`, it terminates the main thread while allowing the process to continue. This is as expected.

If you call `exit()` (or an implicit exit from by returning) instead, it'll terminate the whole process and you will see `printHello` terminated as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a good resource [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Management) but to quote the part which explains your problem:

> Discussion on calling pthread_exit() from main():
>
> - There is a definite problem if main() finishes before the threads it spawned if you don't call pthread_exit() explicitly. All of the threads it created will terminate because main() is done and no longer exists to support the threads.
> - By having main() explicitly call pthread_exit() as the last thing it does, main() will block and be kept alive to support the threads it created until they are done.